# Which link is clicked in asp.net gridview row

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am adding two links and some plain text in same cell of gridview, I also have gridview_SelectedIndexChanged function which is called when any of the link is clicked and based of the value from grid I am running my db queries. gridview is also created dynamically so can have different number of rows.

Is there a way to know Link1 or Link2 is clicked in gridview_SelectedIndexChanged function?

```
protected void gridview_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Link1.Clicked)
       {do this}
    elseif (Link2.Clicked)
       {do this}
}
```

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 1):

You would want to track which link is clicked by using an ASP.NET control

`<asp:LinkButton ID="Link1" runat="server" Click="Link1_Click" />`

in your html

Then add an event handler in your backend like

```
 public void Link1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
//add variable marking this link was clicked
link1_clicked = true;
      Response.Redirect("Link1Destination.aspx");
 }
```

and do the same for link2

`<asp:LinkButton ID="Link2" runat="server" Click="Link2_Click" />`

```
 public void Link2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
//add variable marking this link was clicked
link2_clicked = true;
      Response.Redirect("Link2Destination.aspx");
 }
```

Add the boolean variables `link1_clicked` and `link2_clicked` to the top of you backend code. Then when you need to check what has been clicked you can filter though your boolean variables to see what is marked true as clicked with a for-loop.

Basically the Event handlers are your if clicked statements.

Comment: Well that solution didn't work in my case because I am adding those links from code behind in asp gridview ItemTemplate, if I add OnClick within ItemTemplate it's calling it's own on click method and not calling gridview selectedindexchanged function, so I don't know which row was clicked.

Comment: Is a large grid ? You could manually keep track of what row each link is. Unless the grid is dynamically generated then you might not be able to predict this. I'll do some more research on this for you.

Comment: The grid is dynamically generated.